# Magento : Custom Options fields position

Tags: magento-1.7, php, theme, custom-options

Can you help me how can I change the position of Custom Options on product page. I mean: First **product-options** fields are displayed, then **add_to_cart** fields. I'm Very appreciated for your help.[image]

Thanks Duarte for the the answer but, I have now another problem that I want the **product-options** block appear before **add_to_cart** block. thnks again !
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change block position, just access to product in admin page -> **Tab design** -> **Display Product Options In**

and then select **Product Info Column**

**Note:** This works if product view structure wasn't change.

---

**UPDATE (3/1/2015)**

I found your page (a little google search trick). I checked your current html code and with another google trick i found your current theme.

**Your current html:**

[image]

**Correction:**

if you want something like this:

[image]
Move the code i told you. before this one

```
 <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
     <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

after that your code will look like:

```
 <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
      <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
 <?php endif;?>
 <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
      <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
 <?php endif; ?>
```

Your html browser code view after:

[image]

In case you want something like this:

[image]

Check your code and do something like this:

```
 <?php if ($_product->getShortDescription()):?>
      <div class="short-description">
          <h2><?php echo $this->__('Quick Overview') ?>:</h2>
                <div class="std"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, nl2br($_product->getShortDescription()), 'short_description') ?></div>
      </div>
 <?php endif;?>
 <?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && $this->hasOptions()):?>
      <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?>
 <?php endif;?>
```

Your html browser code view after:
[image]

**Last note: Do not copy the code i wrote it's an example I don't know if your magento theme had any change in the original structure.**

Well i hope this helps you and enjoy magento experience!

Comment: Thanks Duarte for the the answer but, I have now another problem that I want the **product-options** block appear before **add_to_cart** block. thnks again !

Comment: Easy.. in catalog/product/view.php find this code <?php echo $this->getChildChildHtml('container1', '', true, true) ?> and move it before Add to Cart

Comment: Duarte, thnks again.

Comment: Check my update